# Adjust spacing of Two-line title in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I am using a customized Beamer-template. This template comes with the problem that a two-line title looks ugly:

[image: ugly title]

Now, I am trying to both increase the vertical spacing of the title and the horizontal spacing of the second line. I simply included these comments in the title:

`\title{This is a title which is too long to fit in one line and this \vspace{.5cm} \hspace{.25cm} template makes the title look ugly when not fitting within one line}`

This simple method only works for either the vertical or the horizontal spacing though, and not for both.

In a second step, I had a look at the .cls file: 
This file defines a new command `\comnetstitle` which will be used in the .tex file to create the titlepage. Here it is:

`\newcommand{\comnetstitle}{{\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{imgs/logos/logo.png}}\begin{frame}[plain]\titlepage\end{frame}}\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}`

Here is where I don't know enough about TeX: Can it be that the `\titlepage`command needs to be expanded?

I am aware I should provide a MWE. So, first of all, you'll need the .cls-file: 
[here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnN2vIxsA5VLiPwqzIliABnCAo7DKw?e=mFulbg)

Then you will need to create a .tex-file like this:

```
\documentclass[table]{tuhh_comnets_presentation}

\author{My Name}
\title{Estimation of Distance in Autonomous Vehicular Platoons \vspace{.5cm} Using Kalman Filters}
\date{August 21, 2019}

\begin{document}
    \comnetstitle
\end{document}
```

On top of this, there are two logos and one background image inserted on the titlepage. I don't think this should be too important though. However, it means you cannot just run this code as you are missing the logos. Maybe you can replace them with figures you have on your own?

Comment: Is there something stopping you from (a) using a shorter title string so that the title fits on one line or (b) omitting the suspect `\vspace` and `\hspace` directives entirely and simply writing `\title{This is a title which is too long to fit in one line and this template makes the title look ugly when not fitting within one line}`? If the title simply has to cover three lines, so be it, right?

Comment: With the information you provided so far, the issue you describe is not reproducible. Could you therefore please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @Mico: well, I don't want the title to look the way it does (see screenshot). The lines are way too close together and the second line is not indented.

Comment: @leandriis: I have tried. You need the .cls file to reproduce this example. I hope you are able to now.

Comment: @user503842: Thanks for adding the MWE. This makes it now possible to reproduce the issue. As a sidenote: the example code can be made compilable without having acces to the images, if one adds the `demo` option to `\documentclass`.

Comment: After some testing, I found out, that the reason for the undesired spacing definitely is the `\hspace*{1em}\vspace*{-1em}` before `\ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi`. Without it, the title definitely looks a lot better, but modifying this template is most likely not the best/cleanest solution.

Comment: thx, leandriis! - What do you think, is it possible to center this title?

Comment: Please add your class file directly to your question instead of hiding it behind some external link. The class file is most likely missing a paragraph break after `\inserttitle`